# Is redirected stdout/stderr buffered in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I'm using install4j to generate Windows executables.
The launcher is configured to redirect stderr and stdout to `log\error.log` resp. `log\output.log`.
This all works as intended, the log files are written in the expected location and with the expected content.

However, I do not know whether output is flushed or buffered.
I.e. if I kill the program via the Task Manager, can I expect to see the last line that was printed to stderr, or can I expect to lose some output?
(Both outcomes would be fine, I just need to know what will happen so I known how to interpret the log files I'm getting, and what to ask of customers to make sure that I get complete logs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection files are flushed for every newline, but not for every character.